# jquery animate not working while creating gallery slider

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am creating a slider image gallery using jquery.

Here is the code when I click on right arrow.

```
 var v=1;
$(".r").click(function(){
aa=1150;
var aa=aa*v;
if(x1>1){
 $(".d1").animate({right: aa.toString()+"px"});
 l=l+1;
 v=v+1;
 x1=x1-1;
 v1=v1-1;
}
```

and here is the code when I click left arrow

```
var v1=1;
 $(".l").click(function(){
 var aa=1150;
 aa=aa*v1;

if(l>1)
 { 
   $(".d1").animate({left: aa.toString()+"px"});
   x1=x1+1;
   l=l-1;
   v1=v1+1;
   v=v-1;
 }
```

And I am initiation some used in the above code variables like this

var l=1;
var x1=18/6;

the problem is when I click right arrow, it scrolls to the right. then when I click on left arrow, it scrolls to the left. But when I click on right arrow, the following line is not working

```
       $(".d1").animate({right: aa.toString()+"px"});
```

following is my html for slider,

```
   <div class="d1">
  <ul>
   <li >
   <a href="#">
    <img style="width=100px;height:70px" src="Toyota/1.jpg"/>
     <span style="width:100px;height:100px;font-size:small;">This is a new toyota1<span><br>
     <span style="width:100px;height:100px;font-size:small;">&nbsp$9,000</span>

   </a>
  </li>

  <li >
    <a href="#">
     <img style="width=100px;height:70px" src="Toyota/1.jpg"/>
       <span style="width:100px;height:100px;font-size:x-small;">This is a new toyota2<span>
      </a>
    </li> 

     ...
```

**Update** Here is the demo

http://profileone.net/slider.html

Comment: please create JSFiddle

Comment: its simple just look at the code and "try" to understand

Comment: As with the code it should work for both the cases. Could you please make try by binding the class to the "click" event

Comment: @VenkataVamshi what? binding what?! dont try to be "cool", just use simple words

Comment: @Alex I just asked you to try $(".r").bind("click",function(){.....});

Comment: @VenkataVamshi click event is working just fine. its "binded" correctly.any more thoughts?

Answer (score 0):

I think all is ok you need to redefine your `animate` method properties that how your html look after clicking both those button

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
  
  var l=1; var x1=18/6;
  
  var v=1;
  var v1=1;
  $(".r").click(function(){
    aa=500;
    var aa=aa*v;
    if(x1>1){
      $( ".d1" ).animate({
        right: aa.toString()+"px",
        fontSize: "3em",
        borderWidth: "5px"
      }, 1500 );
       l=l+1;
       v=v+1;
       x1=x1-1;
       v1=v1-1;
    } 
  });

  $(".l").click(function(){
    var aa=300;
    aa=aa*v1;
    if(l>1)
    { 
     $( ".d1" ).animate({
        left: aa.toString()+"px",
        fontSize: "3em",
        borderWidth: "10px"
      }, 1500 );
      x1=x1+1;
      l=l-1;
      v1=v1+1;
      v=v-1;
    }
  });

});
```

```css
.d1{
  border:1px solid #DEDEDE;
  width:300px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="d1">
  <ul>
   <li >
   <a href="#">
    <img style="width=100px;height:70px" src="Toyota/1.jpg"/>
     <span style="width:100px;height:100px;font-size:small;">This is a new toyota1<span><br>
     <span style="width:100px;height:100px;font-size:small;">&nbsp$9,000</span>

   </a>
  </li>

  <li >
    <a href="#">
     <img style="width=100px;height:70px" src="Toyota/1.jpg"/>
       <span style="width:100px;height:100px;font-size:x-small;">This is a new toyota2<span>
      </a>
    </li> 
  </ul>
</div>
     <div class="l">Left</div>
     <div class="r">Right</div>
```